# Parallelism with @sync @async in Julia

Tags: dataframe, asynchronous, synchronization, julia

I have some heavy csv table that i would like to import in parallel with @sync @sync macros.
Not very familiar to this, I tried this way :

```
#import files
@sync @async begin
    df1=CSV.File(libname*"df1.csv")|> DataFrame!
    df2=CSV.File(libname*"df2.csv")|> DataFrame!
end
```

I have the task done, but the data subset I make after seems to be impacted :

```
select!(df1, Not("Var1"))

ArgumentError : Column :Var1 not found in the data frame
```

*PS : without @sync macro the code works well*

I probably make something wrong. Any idea would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@sync @async` do not do anything in your code other than introducing a `begin`... `end` block with its local scope.

What happens here is that you are creating a new scope and never modify the global values of `df1` and `df2` - rather than that you are seeing their old values.

If I/O is the bottleneck in your code the correct code would be the following:

```
dfs = Vector{DataFrame}(undef, 2)
@sync begin
    @async dfs[1]=CSV.File(libname*"df1.csv")|> DataFrame!
    @async dfs[2]=CSV.File(libname*"df2.csv")|> DataFrame!
end
```

However, usually it is not the I/O that is the issue but rather the CPU. In that case green threads are not that much useful and you need normal regular threads:

```
dfs = Vector{DataFrame}(undef, 2)
Threads.@threads for i in 1:2
    dfs[i]=CSV.File(libname*"df$i.csv")|> DataFrame!
end
```

Note that for this code to use multi-threading you need to set the `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` system variable before running Julia such as:

```
set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=2
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful to me.